# Imported products not showing up on front end - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, import, products, csv

tried searching but couldn't find an answer. Apologies in advance if it's a duplicate question.

I've imported a bunch of products to a new Magento 2 setup. I created the CSV files and added all necessary attributes associated with products etc.

Import occurs ( I run into the url_key issue which for now I'm resolving by adding random unique garbage values into each product cell).

Products show up on the backend catalog but don't show up on the front-end even if I reindex everything, clear the cache etc. But if I open up a product on the backend and then 'save' it, it pops up on the store. Now this won't be feasible as I'll be importing 100+ products, to go and 'save' each product. Tried multiple things but nothing seems to help.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be grateful! Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is a column name : `_product_websites`? You set these values?

Comment: Ah! Thank you. Set it to base, re-indexed,  and it worked! For some reason I had tried with base before but hadn't re-indexed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to check our import Csv is that we should export a Csv default Magento, make a comparison between column values in our Csv file and default. Make sure our values is correct. And then, try to import a small piece of our Csv. If importing successfully, try to import with all products Csv.

Remember that, we should re-index and clear Magento Cache.

In your case, we should check `_product_websites`.